# Regarding using anyenv, rbenv, ndenv in production environment, CentOS7.*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, centos, rbenv

Currently I'm creating the web service with CentOS7.* and ruby on rails 5.* and ruby 2.* and node.js 6.*.
In the development environments, I'm using anyenv and rbenv and ndenv. Since the installing of ruby and node.js and the exchanging of their versions are easy.

Now I'd like to adopt these tools(anyenv, rbenv, ndenv) in the production environment, too. However, I have never used them in the production.
Also, CentOS7.* does not support them officially. Generally, I think using the packages that are supported by CentOS officially is safer. I'm worried about the troubles which were occurred by using them in the production.

Could you tell me if there is anyone who have experienced to use the tools(anyenv, rbenv, ndenv) in the production environment. Did you have any troubles or etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Docker (or nvm for just Node) and Ubuntu. I recommend NOT using the `*env` or CentOS because they are not as well-supported or complete in terms of out-of-the-box functionality.

Comment: Thanks. It was some help.